# How to make twig rules based on paths?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to make some rules in twig based on current page path. To be precise I want to make the page template look a little different when node is in edit form, revision history page and translation overview.

I want to do something like this, but doesn't seem like working;

```
{% if path('<current>') is path('entity.node.edit_form') %}
```

I want to make rules for all these paths;

```
entity.node.edit_form
entity.node.version_history
entity.node.revision
entity.node.content_translation_overview
entity.node.content_translation_add
entity.node.content_translation_edit
```

Are all available at any page template where a node will be rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the route name in a variable in preprocess

**mytheme.theme**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['route_name'] = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
}
```

and use it in twig:

**page.html.twig**

```
{% if route_name == 'entity.node.edit_form' %}
  This is a node edit form.
{% endif %}
```